# Perl: how to match a variable number of patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I want to grep some information from a column in a file, the column could contain a variable number of instances I'm interested in, see below for a simple example

```
chr8    +       120807654       121847348       Cdh13   unnamed (-46405)                                                                
chr2    +       167514414       167515918       Cebpb   unnamed (+3335), unnamed (+89835)
```

I want to use the number(s) in the parenthesis of the last column and do some calculation later. Now I'm having trouble to use regular expression to get all those numbers out because some lines have only 1 "unnamed (###)" while some lines have more than 1. How to I treat this?

Thanks!

Comment: I figure I can read the last column and split it based on a the comma and then process each pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    @matches = m/\(([+-]\d+)\)/g;
    print join(",", @matches) . "\n";
}
```

`/g` will match all words so all your number will be in `@matches` array.